# What is the phase and magnitude response of white noise?

Tags: fft, noise, python

I would like to create white noise in the frequency domain, and then transform it to the time domain using python. To understand the problem, I simply generated white noise in the time domain, and transformed it to freq domain:

```
import scipy.signal as sg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

e = np.random.normal(0,1,1e3)
E = sg.fft(e)

plt.figure("Bode plot")
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title("Magitude")
plt.plot(abs(E))
plt.subplot(212)
plt.title("Phase")
plt.plot(np.angle(E))
plt.show()
```

I does not look at all as I expected:
[image: Bode plot of white noise]
Questions:

- Isn't white noise supposed to have a flat magnitude response? (equal amounts for all frequencies)
- What is the relationship between the standard deviation (1 in my example) and the magnitude and phase?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Isn't white noise supposed to have a flat magnitude response? 
>       (equal amounts for all frequencies)

The *expected* magnitude response of white noise is flat (this is what JasonR calls the power spectral density).  Any particular instance of a white noise sequence will not have precisely flat response (this is what JasonR's comment refers to as the power spectrum).

[In fact, the Fourier transform of white noise is... white noise!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#White_noise_vector)

> What is the relationship between the standard deviation 
>       (1 in my example) and the magnitude and phase?

There will be no relationship between the standard deviation and the phase.  As for the magnitude, suppose $n(t)$ is stationary white noise with zero mean and standard deviation $\sigma$. Then the autocorrelation (covariance) is:

$$
R_{nn}(\tau) = E[n(t)n(t+\tau)] = \sigma^2\delta(\tau)
$$

So the power spectral density is just $\sigma^2$ (though for discrete-time, there will be a scaling based on the duration of the signal).

---

Questions from comment:

> 1. When you say that the Fourier transform is also white noise, 
>      how can I measure the std-dev when the transform is complex? Real, 
>      imaginary part or some combination?

Assume that our noise is discrete-time and is $n[m]$ (zero mean, Gaussian, white noise with variance $\sigma^2$).  Then the transform is:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
N[k] &=& \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} n[m] e^{-j2\pi mk/M} \\
 &=& \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} n[m] \cos(2\pi mk/M) + j n[m] \sin(2\pi mk/M)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

and the expected value is:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
E\left[N[k]\right] &=& E\left[\sum_{m=0}^{M-1} n[m] e^{-j2\pi mk/M} \right]\\
&=& \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} E\left[n[m]\right] e^{-j2\pi mk/M} \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The variance of the real part is given by:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
E\left[ (\Re N[k])^2 \right] &=& E \left [ \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} n[m] \cos(2\pi mk/M)  \cdot \sum_{p=0}^{M-1} n[p] \cos(2\pi pk/M) \right ]\\
&=& E\left[ \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} \sum_{p=0}^{M-1} n[m]n[p] \delta[n-p] \cos(2\pi mk/M)\cos(2\pi pk/M) \right]\\
&=& \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} E\left[ n[m]^2 \right]\cos^2(2\pi mk/M)\\
&=& \sigma^2\sum_{m=0}^{M-1} \cos^2(2\pi mk/M)\\
&=& \sigma^2 \left( \frac{M}{2} +  \frac{\cos(M+1) 2\pi k/M \sin(2\pi Mk/M) }{ 2 \sin (2\pi k/M) } \ \ \ \right)\\
&=& \frac{\sigma^2 M}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I believe the imaginary part will behave the same way.

> 2. Could you please enlighten me how the duration of the signal relates 
>      to the power spectral density (for discrete time situations)

I believe that (based on the above derivation), the power spectral density (the expected value of the square of the DFT) will scale linearly as the duration.

> 3. If the phase is not affected by the std-dev, what determines the 3 degree amplitude, and the type of distribution (seems to be uniform rather than normal)

[Check out the table on page 2 of this PDF file](https://radarsp.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/4/7/21471216/dft_of_noise.pdf). it says that the argument (phase) of the coefficients will be uniformly distributed, as you state. Screenshot of the table included below.

[image]

Comment: Specifically, the two concepts that the OP is confusing are the *power spectral density* of white noise and the *power spectrum* of one particular realization of a white noise random process.

Comment: Thanks! I have some follow-up questions. 
1: When you say that the Fourier transform is also white noise, how can I measure the std-dev when the transform is complex? Real, imaginary part or some combination?
2: Could you please enlighten me how the duration of the signal relates to the power spectral density (for discrete time situations)
3: If the phase is not affected by the std-dev, what determines the 3 degree amplitude, and the type of distribution (seems to be uniform rather than normal)

Comment: Perfect! This explains all the features of the frequency response. It is now clear to me that the amplitude of the phase was not 3, but $\pi$, and that the std-dev of the real and imaginary parts simply depends on the amount of elements in the vector. I can also confirm, by experiment, that the imaginary part also has a variance of $\frac{\sigma^2 M}{2}$.

Comment: This is the current link to PDF document referenced above (https://radarsp.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/4/7/21471216/dft_of_noise.pdf), which is broken.

Comment: @Guest Thanks! In the future, just try to edit the answer with the new link. It won't go directly as it will need to be reviewed by a higher-rep user, but it will get there (and get you +2 rep in the process).