# Correlation between real and imaginary parts of a Fourier transform of zero mean Gaussian

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

From this [previous post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8418/what-is-the-phase-and-magnitude-response-of-white-noise), the real and imaginary parts of the Fourier transform of a zero mean Gaussian are uncorrelated (and i.i.d. Gaussians)

This some how seems counter-intuitive. It seems if the real part has a large intensity, then the imaginary part should be small. I read through the [proof](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mrichard/DFT%20of%20Noise.pdf) linked from the previous post, but I don't have a good intuitive feel from this proof.

Can you provide an intuitive explanation of why this is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall the following [properties of the Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships):

- If $x(t)$ is an [even function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions), then its Fourier transform $X(\omega)$ is purely real.
- If $x(t)$ is an [odd function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions), then its Fourier transform $X(\omega)$ is purely imaginary.

Thus, we can think of the real and imaginary parts of the Fourier transform of a zero-mean Gaussian random process $x(t)$ as the Fourier transforms of two separate inputs $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$: the components of the process that have even and odd symmetry, respectively. [We split the process into these components as follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5274/how-do-i-divide-a-function-into-even-and-odd-sections):

$$
x_e(t) = \frac{x(t)+x(-t)}{2}
$$

$$
x_o(t) = \frac{x(t)-x(-t)}{2}
$$

Note that $x(t) = x_e(t) + x_o(t)$. Moving through this step by step,

- Your observation was that $\text{Re}\{X(\omega)\}$ and $\text{Im}\{X(\omega)\}$ (the real and imaginary parts of the process's DFT) are uncorrelated.
- Using the Fourier transform properties mentioned above, we can deduce that $\text{Re}\{X(\omega)\} = X_e(\omega)$ and $\text{Im}\{X(\omega)\} = X_o(\omega)$; the real and imaginary parts of $X(\omega)$ are none other than the Fourier transforms of $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$, respectively.
- Therefore, your observation is equivalent to saying that $X_e(\omega)$ and $X_o(\omega)$ are uncorrelated.
- Since the Fourier transform is a one-to-one mapping between the time and frequency domains, I posit that the lack of correlation between $X_e(\omega)$ and $X_o(\omega)$ would imply a lack of correlation between $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$ as well.

What is the correlation between $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$? Simple:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(x_e(t)x_o(t)) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\left(\frac{x(t)+x(-t)}{2}\right)\left(\frac{x(t)-x(-t)}{2}\right)\right) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(x^2(t) - x^2(-t)\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(\mathbb{E}(x^2(t)) - \mathbb{E}(x^2(-t))\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(\sigma^2 - \sigma^2\right) \\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

As expected, the even and odd components are uncorrelated. So, to summarize, I would say the following:

- The real and imaginary components of a Fourier transform correspond to the individual Fourier transforms even and odd components of the input function.
- For a zero-mean Gaussian random process, these even and odd components are uncorrelated.
- Therefore, their Fourier transforms (the real and imaginary components that you asked about) are also uncorrelated.

**Edit:** To address your followup:

- If $x(t)$ is Gaussian, then its even and odd components $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$ are as well, due to the property that any weighted sum of Gaussian random variables is also Gaussian.
- If $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$ are Gaussian random processes, then their Fourier transforms $X_e(\omega)$ and $X_o(\omega$) are as well. This follows from the same property as the previous statement; if you look at the transform, you're computing a weighted sum of a bunch of Gaussian random variables.
- If $X_e(\omega)$ and $X_o(\omega)$ are Gaussian, and they are uncorrelated with one another (as described above), then they are also independent. This is a property of the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up, why are they also i.i.d. Gaussian?

Comment: I added some more info to the post.

Comment: I think the first added bullet is a bit short. The sum of two independent Gaussian variables is Gaussian, but you're perhaps a bit quick in assuming `x(-t)` and `x(t)` are independent. (They are, because the autocorrelation function of x is a delta function)

Comment: @MSalters: I don't make that assumption. Check out the part above where I show that $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$ are uncorrelated. I don't assume that $x(t)$ is independent of $x(-t)$ there. The expectation operator is linear, so the order of expectation and subtraction can be swapped.

Comment: @JasonR: The added bullet states that the sum of two Gaussians is Gaussian, _therefore_ `x(t)` is Gaussian implies `xe(t)` is Gaussian. That makes sense: `xe(t) = x(t) + x(-t)`, the sum of two Gaussians. But the real theorem is that the sum of two independent Gaussians is Gaussian. Thus to prove `xe(t)` is Gaussian that way means proving `x(-t)` is independent.

Comment: @MSalters: I see what you're saying; good point. You are correct in that the independence of $x(t)$ and $x(-t)$ follows straightforwardly from the whiteness of $x(t)$.