# How to generate random samples of Gaussian distribution directly in the frequency domain?

Tags: noise, python, gaussian, scipy, numpy

One can easily draw (pseudo-)random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution by using, say, NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
```

Now, consider the Fast Fourier transform of `s`:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
sHat = fft(s)
```

Considering ["the Fourier transform of white noise is white noise"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8418/what-is-the-phase-and-magnitude-response-of-white-noise?answertab=active#tab-top):

Can we generate `sHat` directly without the Fourier-transform of `s`?

---

I have recently tried to discuss a practical implementation of such thought [herein](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49896177/3393574).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but... you'll need to keep symmetry if your original time-domain signal is real-valued.

If a signal $x$ is real-valued, then its DFT $X$ will exhibit complex-conjugate symmetry:
$$
X[k] = X^*[N-k].
$$

So you can generate $N$ Gaussian pseudo-random noise samples, $g[n]$, and place them in the frequency domain noise vector, $\epsilon$ as:
$$
\epsilon[k] =  g[k] + j g[k+N/2] 
$$
for  $k \in \{ 0, 1, \ldots, N/2-1\}$ and
$$
\epsilon[k] = \epsilon^*[N-k] 
$$
for $k \in \{ N/2, N/2+1, \ldots, N-1 \}$ where $\epsilon^*$ is the complex conjugate of $\epsilon$ and is equal to $\Re[{\epsilon}] - \Im[{\epsilon}]$ (i.e. the same real part and the negative of the imaginary part).

Comment: Peter: As you probably know, I'm a beginner.  When you have a chance, could you explain why that's necessary and what $\epsilon^{*}$ is. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds added some details. Let me know if more is needed.

Comment: Peter: I'll have to look at the detailed version carefully. If I don't get back to you, I either understand it or I'm too lost it to even have a question. thanks.

Comment: @ Peter K: I think I get it. Since the DFT ( and the FFT ) uses the complex exponential, the summation assumes complex conjugate symmetry  of the observations . Is there a FFT algorithm that uses the trigonometric representation so that the conjugate symmetry issue does not arise ? Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds  [There exist real-only FFT algorithms.](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra291/spra291.pdf)  But if the signal is real-valued, the complex conjugate symmetry will always arise.

Comment: K: Thanks.  That looks like a useful reference. I'll check it out.